# Swift - Passing closure to method

Tags: ios, swift

I just started learning Swift after 2 years away from iOS development and I seem to be stuck into the closure as argument syntax. I have the following method in a class:

```
func onFollwersButtonTouched(cb: () -> Void) {
    self.onFollowingTouchedCb = cb
}
```

And I try to set this callback on another class:

```
cell.onFollowersTouchedCb({ () -> Void in

})
```

This code does not compile. The compiler error is:

```
Error:(115, 14) cannot convert the expression's type '() -> Void' to type '() -> Void'
```

And I have no idea what is going on. I have tried the syntax on Apple's Swift book but it was unsuccessful as well.

Comment: How is `onFollowersTouchedCb` declared?

Comment: var onFollowersTouchedCb : (() -> Void) = {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either call method with closure parameter:

```
cell.onFollowersTouched({ () -> Void in

})
```

or assign closure to variable:

```
cell.onFollowersTouchedCb = { () -> Void in

}
```

You are currently calling `onFollowersTouchedCb` with closure parameter, while has no parameters declared.

Comment: I was so completely focused on the closure syntax itself that I did not notice the typo on the method call. I'm feeling dumb now o.O. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
cell.onFollowersTouchedCb({ () -> Void in

})
```

is not setting the closure. You need to perform an actual assign:

```
cell.onFollowersTouchedCb = {
    // Do something
}
```